# Green onions transcription

Tags: piano, sheet-music

https://www.musicnotes.com/sheetmusic/green-onions/7837

Which one of these transcriptions is more correct; the first one or second one? It seems the key isn't written correctly in the HD piano version but they sound similar. The HD piano version sounds more correct for the 4 + to end the measure but I kinda like the sound of the intervals in the bass.

Comment: Why not  take the parts you like from both versions and combine them?

Answer (score 2):

You're right about that key signature. And I agree about those bare-fifths in the bass. AND I agree with PiedPiper about combining bits you like.

Perhaps arranging the left-hand notes into this pattern

[image]
Etc.

might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Played this recently, and the chart was in 3♭s. Were it in F minor, 4♭s would be appropriate. However, were it in F Dorian, 3♭s would be correct.